# Encoding categorical data to dummy variables using modified OneHotEncoder in python?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, encode

This is my code, I was trying to dummy encode the categorical data of the first column of 'X' but this isn't working, when I visited the `OneHotEncoder` documentation page it said that `OneHotEncoder` has been changed. I wasn't able to figure out how to use this changed `OnehotEncoder`.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
onehotencoder=OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X[:, 0]=onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is several issues here.

- First, the one-hot-encoder will return an array with several columns while the input will be a single one. Therefore, you assignment will fail.

*Then, scikit-learn will return a numpy array. So there in no need to use `toarray`.

- Finally, you probably want to apply the encoding on some of the columns and let some other column untouched (or maybe apply another processing). In this case, you want to use what is called a `ColumnTransformer`. You can look at the following example which illustrate perfectly how to make such preprocessing: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-compose-plot-column-transformer-mixed-types-py